# Critique: I need honest feedback on my logo that is supposed to resemble a map pin

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, critique

[image]

Please give feedback and criticism on shadow and highlights and whether it does a good job of resembling what it is meant to? Also, how can I add more depth?

Comment: While I am inclined to agree with Webster when it comes to making a button on an app resemble something familiar for users sake. I don’t entirely agree that you should follow this advice for your logo. In fact I don’t think it’s a very good idea at all to follow the same design you see everywhere for a logo from a legal standpoint. It's already tricky enough trying to make your logo different enough from others. I can see some value in continuing your design path to provide some form of originality, or if it applies to an older crowd, some nostalgia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map pin icons/symbols are already a thing and they look like this:

[image]

Because they are established and people associate "Map Pin" with this shape you might want to consider following the trend. There is one example of your kind of pin here but its the odd man out.

If you want to keep your pin style you might consider rotating it a bit so it doesn't look like a lollipop.

Don't show the point of the pin if its supposed to be stuck in a map.

Don't make the head too glossy. To add depth add shadows to the parts that are farther away and add light colors to the closer parts.

The grey metal is way too dim for the bright red head.

Look at the one pin in the above example and what they did to add depth: a gradient highlight on the ball and a shadow that recedes away from you. Also a shadow where the pin sticks into the surface. These might be good ideas for yours.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the 'ball' is not centered on the pin but it could be just me...

You could add a gradient/shadows/highlights to the ball to make it look more 'sphere-like'.

Perhaps have the pin appear as if it's stuck into the surface?

Looks good though!

Comment: Thank You! I'm always feeling a little too nervous, especially since I'm just starting to design vector art.